# VS code insider version

Tags: visual-studio-code

I’ve just installed VS Code and don’t remember getting asked if I wanted to join the insider version. I don’t want the insider version. My question is how do I know whether I have the insider version or not?

I have not encountered any problems yet with my installed version but I know there could be problems if I have the insider version

Comment: the insider version has a green icon on the task bar

Comment: `Help/About`  menu.